# jQuery Plugin that makes animations happen at certain points when you scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scroll, effect

I'm looking for a `jQuery` plugin (or a tutorial) that allows me to create the Javascript scrolling effect thingy.

I'm sure most of you have seen it a thousand times, but here's [an example](http://bwm.com/) in case you don't know what I mean.

Comment: Google : parallax jQuery plugin

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a plugin exists, but this should be a fairly trivial task of monitoring `scrollTop`.

```
var tmr = window.setInterval(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {
    //trigger animation
  }
}), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code makes the bar fade to .5 opacity when the screen is scrolled more than 100 pixels from the top. You can add in your own jQuery to do other animations.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#nav-bar').stop().css('opacity', '.5');
        } else {
            $('#nav-bar').stop().css('opacity', '1');
        }
    });
```